# Android Geofencing with Google Play Services 6.5.87

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-api-client, geofencing

I have no problem with Google Play Services 6.1.71 (because everything works well) but not the same thing with newer version (6.5.87).

I already know `LocationClient` class is deprecated in 6.5.87 Google Play Services class and I have little problem with converting [old GeofenceDetection sample.](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/GeofenceDetection.zip)

1. First issue I have, with new Play Services I haven't find `OnAddGeofencesResultListener` and `OnRemoveGeofencesResultListener` that I used to handle errors on console;
2. Second issue (main problem) is adding geofence point. When I try to add one to request I receive a pending indefinite...

The code that I have modified is:

**ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.java**

```
public class ReceiveTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * Sets an identifier for this class' background thread
     */
    public ReceiveTransitionsIntentService() {
        super("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService");
    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents
     *
     * @param intent The Intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided
     *               to Location Services (inside a PendingIntent) when you call addGeofences()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Create a local broadcast Intent
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

        // Give it the category for all intents sent by the Intent Service
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);
        GeofencingEvent geoFenceEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

        // First check for errors
        if (geoFenceEvent.hasError()) {
            // Get the error code
            int errorCode = geoFenceEvent.getErrorCode();

            // Get the error message
            String errorMessage = LocationServiceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this, errorCode);

            // Log the error
            Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_error_detail, errorMessage));

            // Set the action and error message for the broadcast intent
            broadcastIntent.setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR).putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS, errorMessage);

            // Broadcast the error *locally* to other components in this app
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

            // If there's no error, get the transition type and create a notification
        } else {
            // Get the type of transition (entry or exit)
            int transition = geoFenceEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

            // Test that a valid transition was reported
            if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) || (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {

                // Post a notification
                List<Geofence> geofences = geoFenceEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
                String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];
                for (int index = 0; index < geofences.size(); index++) {
                    geofenceIds[index] = geofences.get(index).getRequestId();
                }
                String ids = TextUtils.join(GeofenceUtils.GEOFENCE_ID_DELIMITER, geofenceIds);
                String transitionType = getTransitionString(transition);

                sendNotification(transitionType, ids);

                // Log the transition type and a message
                Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_title, transitionType, ids));
                Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text));

                // An invalid transition was reported
            } else {
                // Always log as an error
                Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                        getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, transition));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
     * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the main Activity.
     *
     * @param transitionType The type of transition that occurred.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String transitionType, String ids) {

        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Adds the main Activity to the task stack as the parent
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Set the notification contents
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_title, transitionType, ids))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    /**
     * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
     *
     * @param transitionType A transition type constant defined in Geofence
     * @return A String indicating the type of transition
     */
    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_unknown);
        }
    }
}
```

**GeofenceRequester.java**

```
public class GeofenceRequester implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // Storage for a reference to the calling client
    private final Activity mActivity;

    // Stores the PendingIntent used to send geofence transitions back to the app
    private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;

    // Stores the current list of geofences
    private ArrayList<Geofence> mCurrentGeofences;

    // Stores the current instantiation of the location client
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /*
     * Flag that indicates whether an add or remove request is underway. Check this
     * flag before attempting to start a new request.
     */
    private boolean mInProgress;

    public GeofenceRequester(Activity activityContext) {
        // Save the context
        mActivity = activityContext;

        // Initialize the globals to null
        mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
        mGoogleApiClient = null;
        mInProgress = false;
    }

    /**
     * Set the "in progress" flag from a caller. This allows callers to re-set a
     * request that failed but was later fixed.
     *
     * @param flag Turn the in progress flag on or off.
     */
    public void setInProgressFlag(boolean flag) {
        // Set the "In Progress" flag.
        mInProgress = flag;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current in progress status.
     *
     * @return The current value of the in progress flag.
     */
    public boolean getInProgressFlag() {
        return mInProgress;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current PendingIntent to the caller.
     *
     * @return The PendingIntent used to create the current set of geofences
     */
    public PendingIntent getRequestPendingIntent() {
        return createRequestPendingIntent();
    }

    /**
     * Start adding geofences. Save the geofences, then start adding them by requesting a
     * connection
     *
     * @param geofences A List of one or more geofences to add
     */
    public void addGeofences(List<Geofence> geofences) throws UnsupportedOperationException {

        /*
         * Save the geofences so that they can be sent to Location Services once the
         * connection is available.
         */
        mCurrentGeofences = (ArrayList<Geofence>) geofences;

        // If a request is not already in progress
        if (!mInProgress) {
            // Toggle the flag and continue
            mInProgress = true;

            // Request a connection to Location Services
            requestConnection();

            // If a request is in progress
        } else {

            // Throw an exception and stop the request
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Request a connection to Location Services. This call returns immediately,
     * but the request is not complete until onConnected() or onConnectionFailure() is called.
     */
    private void requestConnection() {
        getLocationClient().connect();
    }

    /**
     * Get the current location client, or create a new one if necessary.
     *
     * @return A LocationClient object
     */
    private GoogleApiClient getLocationClient() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        return mGoogleApiClient;

    }

    /**
     * Once the connection is available, send a request to add the Geofences
     */
    private void continueAddGeofences() {

        // Get a PendingIntent that Location Services issues when a geofence transition occurs
        mGeofencePendingIntent = createRequestPendingIntent();

        // Send a request to add the current geofences
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, mCurrentGeofences, mGeofencePendingIntent);
    }

    /**
     * Get a location client and disconnect from Location Services
     */
    private void requestDisconnection() {

        // A request is no longer in progress
        mInProgress = false;

        getLocationClient().disconnect();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services once the location client is connected.
     *
     * Continue by adding the requested geofences.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // If debugging, log the connection
        Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, mActivity.getString(R.string.connected));

        // Continue adding the geofences
        continueAddGeofences();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services once the location client is disconnected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Turn off the request flag
        mInProgress = false;

        // In debug mode, log the disconnection
        Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, mActivity.getString(R.string.disconnected));

        // Destroy the current location client
        mGoogleApiClient = null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a PendingIntent to send with the request to add Geofences. Location Services issues
     * the Intent inside this PendingIntent whenever a geofence transition occurs for the current
     * list of geofences.
     *
     * @return A PendingIntent for the IntentService that handles geofence transitions.
     */
    private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {

        // If the PendingIntent already exists
        if (null != mGeofencePendingIntent) {

            // Return the existing intent
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;

            // If no PendingIntent exists
        } else {

            // Create an Intent pointing to the IntentService
            Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.class);
            /*
             * Return a PendingIntent to start the IntentService.
             * Always create a PendingIntent sent to Location Services
             * with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, so that sending the PendingIntent
             * again updates the original. Otherwise, Location Services
             * can't match the PendingIntent to requests made with it.
             */
            return PendingIntent.getService(
                    mActivity,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Implementation of OnConnectionFailedListener.onConnectionFailed
     * If a connection or disconnection request fails, report the error
     * connectionResult is passed in from Location Services
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        // Turn off the request flag
        mInProgress = false;

        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity,
                        GeofenceUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*
             * If no resolution is available, put the error code in
             * an error Intent and broadcast it back to the main Activity.
             * The Activity then displays an error dialog.
             * is out of date.
             */
        } else {

            Intent errorBroadcastIntent = new Intent(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_CONNECTION_ERROR);
            errorBroadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES)
                    .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_CONNECTION_ERROR_CODE,
                            connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).sendBroadcast(errorBroadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve problem #2?  I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

To replace `OnAddGeofencesResultListener` use ResultCallback

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi
  .addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, mCurrentGeofences, mGeofencePendingIntent)
  .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(Status status) {
      if (status.isSuccess()) {
        // Success
      }
    }
 });
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of setResultCallback() here?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky to do whatever his OnAddGeofencesResultListener was doing

Comment: @dzeikei  But how does that discern between the different Geofence events (i.e. Enter, Dwelling, Exit)??

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky this is callback containing the result from trying to add geofences being monitored. It is not a callback for the actual geofence events being triggered by moving around.

Comment: And there is no discerning between adding/removing with this.

Comment: @BillMote I don't understand what you mean. If you added a geofence, the result must be from adding?

Comment: Formerly there were onAdd... and onRemove... callbacks.

Comment: You need 2 separate callback handlers: one for adding and one for removing.